# With Spring boot and integration DSL, getting error ClassNotFoundException integration.history.TrackableComponent

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

Trying a very basic JMS receiver using Spring Boot, Integration and DSL. I have worked on XML based on Spring Integration, but am new to Spring Boot and DSL.

This is a code sample that I have so far

```
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableJms
public class JmsReceiver {

    static String mailboxDestination = "RETRY.QUEUE";


    @Configuration
    @EnableJms
    @IntegrationComponentScan
    @EnableIntegration
    public class MessageReceiver {

        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows
                    .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(this.connectionFactory())
                            .destination(mailboxDestination))
                    .transform((String s) -> s.toUpperCase())
                    .get();
        }
        //for sneding message
        @Bean
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory acFac = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
            acFac.setBrokerURL("tcp://crsvcdevlnx01:61616");
            acFac.setUserName("admin");
            acFac.setPassword("admin");
            return new CachingConnectionFactory(acFac);
        }
    }


    //Message send code
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JmsReceiver.class);

        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
        System.out.println("Sending a new mesage.");

        MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createTextMessage("ping!");
            }
        };
        jmsTemplate.send(mailboxDestination, messageCreator);

        context.close();
    }
}
```

And, I get this error when running with Gradle.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]: Factory method 'inboundFlow' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/history/TrackableComponent
    reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.history.TrackableComponent
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

My gradle dependencies:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration",
        "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms",
        "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.1.1.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-flow:1.0.0.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.2.2.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.1.0.RELEASE",
        "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-flow:1.0.0.RELEASE",
        "org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.11.2",
```

***UPDATE.. SOLVED: Thanks much.*** Changed two things:

1. Cleaned up gradle dependencies based on your advice. New ones looks like this:

   ```
   compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey",

           "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",
           "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor",
           "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration",
           "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms",
           "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.1.0.RELEASE",
           "org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.11.2"
   ```
2. Code was throwing constructor error about not being able to instantiate `<init>` in the inner class. Changed the Inner class to static.  New Code:

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @IntegrationComponentScan
   @EnableJms
   public class JmsReceiver {

       static String lsamsErrorQueue = "Queue.LSAMS.retryMessage";
       static String fatalErrorsQueue = "Queue.LSAMS.ManualCheck";

       //receiver
       @EnableJms
       @EnableIntegration
       @Configuration
       public static class MessageReceiver {
           @Bean
           public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlow() {
               return IntegrationFlows
                       .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(this.connectionFactory())
                               .destination(lsamsErrorQueue))
                       //call LSAMS REST service with the payload received
                       .transform((String s) -> s.toUpperCase())

                       .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(this.connectionFactory())
                               .requestDestination(fatalErrorsQueue))
                       .get();
           }
           @Bean
           ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
               ActiveMQConnectionFactory acFac = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
               acFac.setBrokerURL("tcp://crsvcdevlnx01:61616");
               acFac.setUserName("admin");
               acFac.setPassword("admin");
               return new CachingConnectionFactory(acFac);
           }
       }

       //Message send code
       public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable {
           AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                   new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JmsReceiver.class);

           JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
           System.out.println("Sending a new mesage.");

           MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {
               @Override
               public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                   return session.createTextMessage("ping!");
               }
           };
           jmsTemplate.send(lsamsErrorQueue, messageCreator);

           context.close();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that fully looks like you have a version mess in your classpath.

First of all you shouldn't mix the same artifacts manually, like you have with `spring-integration-java-dsl` and `spring-integration-flow`. BTW, do you really need the last one?.. I mean is there some reason to keep `spring-integration-flow`? This project is about [Modular Flows](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow).

From other side you don't need to specify `spring-integration-core` if you are based on the Spring Boot (`spring-boot-starter-integration` in your case).

And yes: the `TrackableComponent` has been moved to the `org.springframework.integration.support.management` since Spring Integration 4.2 (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3799).

From here it looks like you use the older Spring Integration version somehow:
- or Spring Boot 1.2.x
- or it is really side-effect of transitive dependency from `spring-integration-flow`...